# .NET Core: Conflicting assembly references

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, arm64

I'm running into a issue that I cant solve for the life of me. I have a .NET Core application on Linux. While building the project I see the following warning:

*Encountered conflict between 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' and 'Runtime:~/.nuget/packages/microsoft.win32.registry/4.7.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'. Choosing 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' because it is a platform item.*

The outcome of this looks to be that the the nuget package for this assembly is not being packaged in the applications output directory as it should, since the build appears to be using a system version of this assembly that came with the dotnet installation.

I've tried just about everything I can think of. Anyone run into this or have ideas of how to resolve? I think I've tried just about everything I can think or have come across online.

Should note also that I'm doing this in Ubuntu 20 on ARM64 and am fairly new to .NET

Comment: Side note: you may want to clarify what is the "issue later". Clearly attempting to use Win32-specific code on Linux is unlikely to succeed, so not sure why that particular assembly would cause problems for your code.

Comment: What is the issue you're going to see later? What have you tried?

Comment: The "issue later" is at the bottom of the question.  The nuget package of the assembly is not being packaged in the app output directory as its supposed to.  I meant to remove the "issue later" piece.

@Train

Ive tried explicitly adding the assembly using PackageReference, and binding redirects

Comment: Have you tried adding the dll to a folder in your project then referencing that folder?

Comment: What did you specify in your proj file concerning runtimeIdentifier and targetFramework? Afaik win32.registry is available only for windows.

Comment: I actually don't have anything specified for RunTimeIdentifier. Also should note that this is a project that works successfully on other machines but those are CentOS x86-64 machines. Im.working with Ubuntu and ARM64